# Groovy, update XML

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing

I'm newbie in Groovy and have to accomplish a task for some Jenkins configuration. Please,  help me with xml parsing. Just in order to simplify the problem(originally it's a huge Jenkins config.xml file), let's take:

```
def input = '''
              <shopping>
                  <category>
                      <item>Pen</item>
                      <color>Red</color>
                  </category>
              <category>
                      <item>Pencil</item>
                      <color>Black</color>
                  </category>
                  <category>
                      <item>Paper</item>
                      <color>White</color>
                  </category>
              </shopping>
    '''
```

The target is to change color for Pen only.

I'm trying:

```
def root = new XmlParser().parseText(input)
def supplies = root.category.find{ it.text() == 'Pen' } 
supplies.parent().color.value() = 'Changed'
```

Looks so simple but I'm totally lost :(
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

....Or use `XmlSlurper` to simplify usage of `color[0]` and `text()`.

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(input)
def supplies = root.category.find{ it.item == 'Pen' }
supplies.color = 'Changed'
```

Comment: Another dumb question, if you don't mind, how can I 'escape' dots in Node names? E.g.: <hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>

Comment: use quotes. For example: `root.example.'hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty'.sample`

Answer (score 3):

Almost there...

```
def root = new XmlParser().parseText(input)
def supplies = root.category.find{ it.item.text() == 'Pen' }
supplies.color[0].value = 'Changed'
```

The thing to note is that color is a Node List whose first node is a text node